# Losing job during first my first year in France!

Tags: france

Let's suppose I am a not europian asseding, and I gained a job permit to work in France from DIRECCTE. I worked for three months and the campany told me that they have to break my trial period due to financial problems and they give me a notice period of one month to look for another job. The problem is that it's my first year in France and in my job permit the name of the campany is noticed. Pratically, what should I do before having another job? Do I have have to gain another job permit in case I find another job? And how this situation is going to affect my stay in France?

Comment: I'm going off a very diluted memory of the time I worked in France (but did not have an issue like this), but there should a government department (OSII?) that gave you your residence permit once you were in France. I would think contacting them first would be smart.

Comment: Do you know what OSII stands for?